# Capturar evento do mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, amigos!
Estou desenvolvendo um menu lateral que contém submenus em C#, porém não consigo achar um método eficaz para exibir os submenus que ficam dentro de um painel. Tentei com evento MouseMove, entretanto não obtive o resultado esperado, pois o painel ainda fica visivel ao mudar de componente. Alguém poderia me ajudar?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @user bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor edite sua pergunta e adicione alguns trechos de código para que seja possível encontrar o problema

Comment: Qual o motivo de não usar o componente "menuStrip" ? 
Ele já tem essa função incorporada para expandir menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações.

Consegui fazer aqui de um jeito que acho atender o que você precisa.
Os eventos usados serão o **MouseHover** e o **MouseLeave**.

Eu criei uma *Panel* que servirá de fundo lateral, esta panel se chamará **pnlMenuLateral**.
Dento da panel do menu adicionei duas labels, uma para abrir o subMenu **Vendas**(lblVendas) e a outra para abrir o subMenu **Cadastros**(lblCadastros).

Quando passar o mouse sobre o nome vendas abre o menu de vendas e recolhe qualquer outro menu aberto. O mesmo vai acontecer com o menu cadastros.

Adicionei ao projeto 2 componentes do tipo **Timer** que nos auxiliará na visualização  dos subMenus. Mude o intervalo destes timers para 5.
Chamarei de **timerVendas** e **timerCadastros**.

Mude o tamanho do Size das panels dos subMenus para Width=0;

Vamos Aos Códigos:

```
// estas duas variáveis controlarão o tamanho das panels dos subMenus
// no meu caso aqui elas tem um whidth = 68, veja qual o tamanho total do 
// seu para que apareçam todos os componentes do subMenu
 int tamanhoVendas = 0;
 int tamanhoCadastros = 0;

// ao passar o mouse  no "lblVendas" é apresentado o submenu de vendas
private void lblVendas_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlCadastros.Size = new Size(pnlCadastros.Width, tamanhoCadastros);
    timerVendas.Start();// estamos escondendo o menu de cadastro
}

// parando o timer de vendas e zerando o tamanho da panel de vendas
private void lblVendas_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timerVendas.Stop();
  tamanhoVendas = 0;
}

// aqui estamos fazendo a verificação para parar ou mostrar o subMenu de Vendas 
private void timerVendas_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tamanhoVendas > 255)
    timerVendas.Stop();
    else
    {
       pnlVendas.Size = new Size(pnlVendas.Size.Width, tamanhoVendas);
       tamanhoVendas += 5;
    }
}
```

Agora Vamos repetir os mesmos passo para o menu de cadastros

```
   private void lblCadastro_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       pnlVendas.Size = new Size(pnlVendas.Width, tamanhoVendas);
       timerCadastros.Start();
   }

    private void lblCadastro_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerCadastros.Stop();
        tamanhoCadastros = 0;
    }

    private void timerCadastros_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tamanhoCadastros > 255)
            timerCadastros.Stop();
        else
        {
            pnlCadastros.Size = new Size(pnlCadastros.Size.Width, tamanhoCadastros);
            tamanhoCadastros += 5;
        }
    }
```

Para Finalizar vamos fazer com que ao sair com o mouse de cima dos nomes do submenu
Os próprios SubMenus se escondam novamente.

Vou fazer isso duas vezes, uma para quando sair com o mouse para cima da panelMenu e outra quando sair com o mouse para o lado do form principal. Veja qual situação te atende ou se igual no meu caso as duas.

```
   private void pnlMenu_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         pnlCadastros.Size = new Size(pnlCadastros.Width, tamanhoCadastros);
         pnlVendas.Size = new Size(pnlVendas.Width, tamanhoVendas);
     }

    private void frmEspandirMenuLateral_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlCadastros.Size = new Size(pnlCadastros.Width, tamanhoCadastros);
        pnlVendas.Size = new Size(pnlVendas.Width, tamanhoVendas);
    }
```

Está ai, eu fiz os testes aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Saudações.

Os eventos são o *MouseLeave* e *MouseEnter*.

primeiro Colocoque as panels de submenus com a propriedade **Visible = false** para que elas iniciem sem aparecer no *form* principal.

Vou supor que os nomes dos menus sejam componentes do tipo ***Labels***, então quando passar o mouse vai mostrar o *SubMenu* e quando sair com o mouse o *SubMenu* desaparece (**SubMenu neste caso = Panel**).

```
private void lblVendas_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pnlVendas.Visible = true;
}

private void lblVendas_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pnlVendas.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Desse modo ele aparece e logo sai, teria que ser um modo em que: quando estivesse o mouse acima do menu ele não sumisse.

Comment: Endendi, não sei se o que você pretende fazer é possível em *WindowsForms*, talvez seja em *WPF*. Mesmo assim acho o componente *MenuStrip* mais conveniênte.